# JAVA_HOME not found in Cloud Foundry deployment

Tags: java, cloud-foundry, pcfdev

I am trying to use the PCF Dev from Pivotal for Cloud Foundry Development.

I want to setup my simple standalone jar file which only stdout hello every secound. I pushed it and everything seems to work fine except the start.

On start I get the following log error:

```
2016-05-10T13:09:45.28+0200 [APP/0]      ERR bash: JAVA_HOME: No such file or directory
```

My manifest.yml

```
applications:
  - name:    cf-test
    no-route: true
    memory:  128M
    instances: 1
    path: /bin/test.jar
    build: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git
```

For me it seems like Java isn't installed properly in the CF-Environment. But how to debugg that?

I really hope someone knows a answer :) Thank you!

**Edit:** I found out that i have to set the Environment-Variable of JAVA_HOME but to what? How to find out the Java Path?

Comment: Set it to the root directory of your Java installation tree.  Search for `set "JAVA_HOME"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I don't get it. I don't think the JAVA_HOME path is the only problem. Is cloud foundry made for applications that doesnt provide a web part? Do i have to configure something special?

Comment: @ekul: did you find the answer to your question? What is the path to the java executable?

Comment: I am searching for the same thing, what is the path to the java executable in the cloud foundry app. The answer doesn't seem to be related to the question at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the docs on the [health-check-type attribute](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#health-check-type)

> Use the `health-check-type` attribute to set the `health_check_type` flag to either `port` or `none`. If you do not provide a `health-check-type` attibute, it defaults to `port`.
>
> ```
> ---
>   ...
>   health-check-type: none
> ```
>
> The command line option that overrides this attribute is `-u`.

Use `none` if your process is not like a web application that binds to a port, and instead is just a background worker that prints some logs.

Comment: This seems like a strange answer to the question of what the path is to the jre in a cloud foundry. What does health-check-type have to do with the path to the java executable for a cf app launched with the java buildpack? I'm still trying to find out the answer to the OP's original question!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very unfriendly point of Cloud Foundry, **it does not set $JAVA_HOME by default**.

Here are the ways how I solved this.

1. Use `Dist Zip` container to push your app to CF, this way you can count on build pack itself to find the Java path.(
   https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/container-dist_zip.md)
2. Use the `Start Command` of Cloud Foundry to set $JAVA_HOME, like:
   `JAVA_HOME=.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/`

The java installation path is directly under the build pack.
`/home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack`. You can find it if you use command line to view your CF.